# Monotouch, xcode 4, Table View Cell template - best practice

Tags: xamarin.ios

i have been trying to figure out the best way writing custum table view cells.

I have found Lots og post but most talk about doing it with a controller class and a dictionary which uses ticks as a key. This seems very much like a hack and not a pattern i would like to use.

http://www.infoq.com/articles/monotouch-custom-tables

However then i found an alternative:
http://www.alexyork.net/blog/2011/07/18/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-with-monotouch-the-correct-way/

this Seems so much cleaner however a hack is needed to be able to wire up oitlets, described in the comments

However even with this all outlets appear to be null and egen rendering a table using a template with this pattern it is empty.

Does anyone know why ?